# Building a web application in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, web-applications, yii

This is a topic which isn't new and I'm reading some articles based on this for the last 3-4 days and I guess I've reached a point where I'd like to ask a question before proceeding further to ensure whether I'm going down the right track.

A bit of background first - 
So I've been working with PHP frameworks like CakePHP, Yii etc. for nearly 4-5 years and I can see how they're tailor made for application development with rich emphasis on MVC, an easy way to store, and manage persistent data either in a database or in a file system etc.

But then it strikes me every time that when starting a new application, I need to build a user management system (login, registration, password recovery with emails, expiry tokens etc.). The one I'm building now will require an ability for users to upload images against an object in the system to show to other users etc. Wordpress has these already built into it's system i.e a comprehensive user management system and a rich feature of managing media uploads.

So I'm thinking of leveraging these already in built features and build my application on top. Of course, Wordpress also has easy ways of creating front end pages, blog articles, adding themes, plugins etc. which I can still continue to use.

So finally getting to the question -

I'm building an online marketplace between buyers and sellers.
Would I rather be better of finding plugins for say CakePHP which do the basic or even comprehensive user management and media management (which I guess were the two main things I wanted to leverage in Wordpress) and then continue making the application in an environment which is flexible and one I'm already comfortable in rather than learning a whole new Wordpress environment in order to just leverage those two features.

I apologise if I haven't been clear in my question. If so, just let me know  and I will provide further clarification.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Regards,

Prathamesh.

Comment: If you are trying to build an ecommerce platform, use those frameworks, which are actually for ecommerce like Prestashop, Magento, etc. You can start with Prestashop as it has a small learning curve, and there are many free modules, and you can develop your own modules as needed.

Comment: Hey mate. I'm not essentially building an ecommerce platfrorm. It's an online marketplace for people to list a type of service and for others to search and buy that service from the user who has listed the service. The user listing the service should have means to easily upload photos and videos for the listing etc.

Comment: Using Wordpress is like shooting your face with a shotgun, especially when it comes to E-Commerce and you want some decent level of security... Wordpress is the worst mess of code and abuse of a relational DB I've seen in an open source project. I wouldn't build anything based on WP. It's popular yea, but for sure not because of it's outstanding code base. Go for Magento, it's a pretty solid base. For everything else use a proper MVC framework. They all feature plugins for user management and other common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at comments here on StackOverflow and various articles on the internet including those with actual examples of writing custom code inside Wordpress, I've come to the decision not to pursue down this path.

Reasons -

1. Finding articles that talk about this topic in detail was hard. This I believe is a good indication that this is not a popular subject. If you do a quick search on Udemy for Building a web application in CakePHP, you'll get a lot of results. That wasn't the case for when I searched for building a web application in Wordpress - 0 results.
2. Came across an article on Sitepoint - https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-framework/. The article was in favour of using Wordpress as a framework and two of the points (User management and Medial management) were listed which were also the two points which I considered when deciding to look into Wordpress as a development framework/foundation. But upon reading the comments, I realised that there is a lot of friction and many developers are against it. The main point that clicked with me is that since Wordpress is not based on MVC (it's procedural), any experience I've gained in the last 4-5 years is not going to be useful and hence even from a practical perspective building an application would take a lot longer (even considering the already built user management and media management system).
3. As far as the user and media management systems, I did find plugins for the various popular PHP frameworks (CakePHP, Yii etc.) and though people said that it wasn't that great as compared to Wordpress, it would definitely be a start and customising those would be much easier than first understanding and then customising the same in Wordpress.

With that, I'd like to say that those who have started on this path and are choosing to move forward should do at their own risk and courage. My opinion is that it would take a lot of time for someone who's coming in from an MVC background. But like someone said in one of the comments on Sitepoint, opinions are like butts, everyone has one but that doesn't mean that they should be out in the public.

Answer (score 0):

Despite, you've already find the answer, I'd like to say that Wordpress is the simpliest way (just install several plugins and that's all). But, in the end you'll face that your WordPress marketplace will sooner or later become no longer custom and not very convenient.
Anyway, for the future, I suggest you to try Sharetribe for this purpose. Or even better solution if you just build your marketplace from scratch using one of famous frameworks (Ruby on Rails for example). I did some research on this field and think that RoR is the optimal variant for custom, stable and secure marketplace. You can read my article [Ruby on Rails Marketplace Development](http://syndicode.co/ruby-on-rails-marketplace-development/) and then decide, what is better for you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm constantly amazed at the misinformation and lack of information on the subject of Yii (or insert your favorite framework) vs WordPress.  For instance, suggesting that WP is procedural and not OOP, etc.

After performance and scalability issues are resolved, the answer is to work in the CMS/Framework you know best and that can best be supported by your client or organization in the event you are no longer with them.

While I consider Yii a much better utilizer of databases, and better for data specific tasks, the truth is that whatever code I want to write can be written for either Yii or WP.